# CD in cmd script different from working Dir in VB.NET app

Tags: vb.net, command-line, cmd, working-directory

I'm launching my VB.NET application from the command line and then using the function IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() in the application to get the current working directory. But the directory returned from this function is always the directory of my VB.NET EXE. If I cd to a directory from the command prompt and then run the VB.NET application, is there a way to get the working directory that the command prompt is using?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is impossible so I found a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

From the command-line, you can use

```
Echo %CD%
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to get the working directory that the CMD prompt is using (if accessible) from my VB.NET application. IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() just gives me the Dir of the EXE. Basically, if I cd to a directory and then launch the exe, which is in a different directory. I want that exe to know what directory was cd'd to. Is that possible?